# Limitations of OOTB Picture Library Slideshow WebPart on Team page

Tags: web-part, library, picture

I apologize for the newbie question, but I am very frustrated trying to use the Picture Library Slideshow WebPart. The photos are downsized without any apparent reason, despite the care with which I size them before importing them.  The web part wants to expand to the entire height of the zone. I'd like more options in setting the caption and alt text.  Are there better solutions for a basic picture rotator with captions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to edit the the webpart to set it at fixed width/height to prevent from being scaled too large at low resolution?

If you're not opposed to using some j-query, one of the options presented here might work for you. http://www.brighthub.com/internet/web-development/articles/94717.aspx

Comment: Yes, I've tried to fix the width and height. But the actual picture size within the web part boundaries still is unpredictable.  Thanks for the j-query suggestions!